# How to handle alias in TrustStore

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore

I am running the Java process (Microservice) and trustStore configured in the JVM parameter. If the Microservice needs to connect the external URL which required the cert to be imported in trustStore.

```
Example: 
example.co.uk -> examplecouk as alias in trustStore
example.com -> examplecom as alias in trustStore
example.in  -> examplein as alias in trustStore
```

How does Java know that which certs and alias to be picked from the trustStore for the particular endpoint as I don't pass/mention the alias in the JVM params? Is it pick randomly?

Comment: For truststore purposes the alias means nothing. It just searches the truststore for a signer of the incoming peer certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

user207421 is nearly correct. To be more exact:

When you as client open an SSL/TLS connection to a server, as part of the handshake the server sends its certificate 'chain' containing its own cert, plus usually one or more linked CA (Certificate Authority) certificates ending with a 'root' CA that should be trusted. See the neighboring Stack https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/ for an epically complete explanation. Public servers normally use a cert issued and signed by a public CA like Digicert, GoDaddy, LetsEncrypt/ISRG which are already in the standard default truststore (for Java in the file `JRE/lib/security/cacerts`) so no action is needed. If a server uses a cert from a off-brand or private CA, or a self-signed cert (from no CA at all), then (for Java) *some* cert in the chain must be added to the client truststore, or otherwise overridden; this is only required to be the *server* cert in the case where the server cert is self-signed (which is a chain by itself and has no relevant CA certs).

Java/JSSE implements this through an `SSLContext` which contains among other things a `TrustManager`, more specifically an `X509ExtendedTrustManager`, which is *initialized* from a truststore. You can create an `SSLContext` explicitly in code from any set of trusted certs (which doesn't even need to be from a file), or use the default context which uses the default truststore file, which defaults to the filename above unless overridden by a system property.

When the server cert chain is received it is passed to the context's TrustManager for validation; among (many!) other checks, at each level of a normal chain, or the single level of a self-signed cert, the JSSE TrustManager looks for an anchor cert (edit) which either *is* the desired cert (same Subject and (Subject)PublicKey) or is the signer of that cert (Subject equals Issuer), and if such an anchor is found it is used validate the cert chain. Note that a normal (CA-issued) leaf cert can have Subject empty if Subject Alternative Name is used instead -- see rfc5280 and rfc2818 -- but a self-signed cert cannot, because it has Subject = Issuer and Issuer must *not* be empty. Certs for different entities (e.g. different servers) normally are expected to have different keys, although a single entity can have multiple certs with either the same key or different keys, and might correspond to multiple server names and/or addresses.

(added) This anchor lookup does not use the alias, and neither does anything else in the validation process, which is why the alias is not and does not need to be specified, and the aliases that are needed for (some) other purposes in a KeyStore file or object have no significance for this purpose.

If the certificate is determined valid in general, for *some* TLS applications (notably HTTPS) the validator *also* checks it is for the correct server, specifically that the CommonName attribute in the Subject field, or an entry in the Subject Alternative Name extension if present (which for public CAs it always is and has been for at least a decade it is) matches the host DNS name or IP adddress in the URL. In older versions of Java (through 6 IIRC) this was not done in JSSE but rather in the calling application(s) or library, such as `HttpsURLConnection`, which as a legacy still has the option to use its own `HostnameVerifier` instead.

All of this can be altered by using a custom `TrustManager` in place of the standard one, and some things like Apache `HttpClient` do so validly, but you will find (too many) answers here and some other Stacks recommending you 'solve' TLS errors by using a neutered `TrustManager` that just accepts any cert, regardless of whether it is actually valid and correct, and thus happily connects and sends sensitive data to, or accepts changes from, any attacker who manages to intercept the IP traffic, which is often pretty easy nowadays.

Comment: While this is a thorough and useful explanation of the process, it doesn’t answer the question:  namely, what is the significance of the aliases in the KeyStores used to initialize a TrustManagerFactory.

Comment: @VGR: see addition.

Comment: adding the inherent security issues of custom, invalidly operating TrustManagers is a nice touch. We need to spread the truth otherwise it will get lost

Answer (score -1):

Alias is a way to directly access the certificate but your keystore has other information regarding the certificate as well. X.509 certificates have a field called SAN (Subject Alternative name) which contains the DNS information of the certificate. When you try to connect to a specific URL, the keystore is looked up for the corresponding DNS name in SAN and correct certificate is picked up.

I hope it clarifies your doubt about java not asking for the alias. Rest assured, there is nothing random in this process.

Comment: This is backwards, and could not work for the overwhelmingly common case where the server cert is issued by a 'real' CA and you don't know which until you receive that cert in the handshake.

Comment: subject alternative name != DNS name. Two completely seperate fields ... even though "many" implementations simply paste the same value into both